# Why isn't power going into my apparatus

Tags: electromagnetism

I am using a LightingWill Waterproof IP67 LED Power Supply:

https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07T1WRQ4H/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

to power a magnetohydrodynamic drive with a circuit diagram that looks like this:
[image]

the solenoids are wrapped around a bunch of iron nails as the core and the electrodes are copper tapes. The direction of current and magnetic field is shown in the circuit diagram (yellow is current, cyan is magnetic field). The whole apparatus submerged in saturated salt water. By the left hand rule, when electricity passed through the salt water, they should be propelled by Ampere force with the direction being perpendicular to the screen and out. However, when I connected everything and plug the power supply into the kitchen socket, nothing happens and there is no voltage inside the circuit. I tested the resistance at the joints between the solenoid branch and the electrode branch and received a resistance at 0.01 ohm. When I disconnect my apparatus and just plug in the power supply, the voltage at the power supply output (the red and black wire) is 12 V, that means the power supply is working. So why didn't I get current into my apparatus? I used 18 AWG wire for my electrode branch (this is the wire that also connects to the power supply) and 12 AWG wire for my electromagnet solenoid.

Comment: the copper tape is not insulated, and have conductive adhesive

Comment: no, there is a pair of coils on the left and right side of a tunnel whose top and bottom is the copper tape electrode. That is, if by "coil" you mean my electromagnet solenoids

Comment: now it makes sense ... the coils are not made from would copper tape ... maybe the power supply is shutting down because of overcurrent

Comment: could you tell me how to solve this issue? I got it on amazon and when I try to ask questions about this product, it doesn't have the option to anymore.

Comment: this is not a discussion forum ... it is a Q&A site ... you asked a question, but you did not supply any infornation about your circuit or about hiw you are measuring the voltage

Comment: please do mot crosspost https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/583628/are-there-resistance-in-my-solenoid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129063/discussion-between-faito-dayo-and-jsotola).

Comment: You are probably drawing too much current from the power supply and causing it to shut down.